# C++ template programming need an extra adressof when T is char*

Tags: c++

So currently i am trying to write my own mysql lib (just for fun and because the mysql connector did not work for me) also i think it is a very good training for template programming. So i created a function that deduces the maxmimum length my string can have , in other words it calculates the needed size for my char array.
(sorry if my english is not right somewhere)

so i created this function

```
        template<typename T,typename... argpack>
    constexpr std::size_t arg_pack_str_length(T first, argpack... rest)
    {

        return (std::is_integral<typename std::decay<T>::type>::value ||
            std::is_floating_point<typename std::decay<T>::type>::value) ?
            std::numeric_limits<typename std::decay<T>::type>::digits :
            c_str_length(&first)/* why to the hell i have to make the adressof here ? */
            + arg_pack_str_length(std::forward<argpack>(rest)...);

    }
```

and this is the base case for this function:

```
std::size_t arg_pack_str_length() { return 1; };
```

and i have made my own string len function that looks like this:

```
    constexpr std::size_t c_str_length(T* c_str)
    {
        std::size_t len = 0;
        if (*c_str++ != '\0')
            return ++len + c_str_length(c_str);
        return len + 1;
    }
```

so my question is, when i call the function like this c_str_length(first)
the compiler thinks that first is of type int ? but it is of type const char * but when i made the function call like this c_str_length(&first) my function does work but when i look in the function with typeid 
which type T* is it tells me const char **. 
so i really dont understand this is there anything i am missing ? 
And even when the type now ist const char ** why the function works with only one * here : (*c_str++ != '\0') i really hope i explained my question right ( sorry again if my english was wrong on some parts)

So i really hope anyone can answer this because this really confuses me.

Gerald

Comment: You should start using proper identifiers instead of obscure names such as `T` or `argpack`. Guessing from your second function `T` is supposed to be a some kind of `char` and you are trying to calculate combined length of c-style string, that is pointers to char. If you expect `first` to be a pointer to null-terminated string and `T` is a char that type of `first` should be `T *`, not just plain `T`, just like you did in `c_str_length`. Also you haven't shown how you actually call `arg_pack_str_length`.

Comment: so thank you for the comment i think i can follow this means if i call a template with char* for example the type T is char afterwards and therefore T* is char** because i thought when i call a template with char* then T is char* and T* is char**    btw: where did i use obscure names ?